# Docker - Why my docker image is so large?

Tags: docker, contains, docker-image

I'm building a image for a development environment on CentOS 7 with postgres and some other essential packages for my project. But the final size is around 900MB, I even remove some packages that I won't use anymore after the building process.

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all && yum -y install epel-release gnupg && \
yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm && \

# Setting global environment variables
ENV PG_VERSION 9.6
ENV PG_HBA /var/lib/pgsql/$PG_VERSION/data/pg_hba.conf
ENV PG_CONF /var/lib/pgsql/$PG_VERSION/data/postgresql.conf
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/pgsql/$PG_VERSION/data

RUN yum update && yum -y install acl gcc gcc-c++ \
    postgresql96 postgresql96-contrib postgresql96-devel \
    postgresql96-server postgresql96-plpython vim perl-CPAN \
    cpanminus perl-DBD-Pg libdbi-dbd-pgsql git unzip pgxnclient python-setuptools && \
        yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools" && \
    cpanm --mirror http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/ --quiet --force --notest App::Sqitch && \
    export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/pgsql-$PG_VERSION/bin" && pgxn install first_last_agg && \
    pgxn install plpgsql_check && pgxn install pgtap && cpan TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::pgTAP && \
    pgxn install geoip && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

USER postgres
RUN /usr/pgsql-$PG_VERSION/bin/initdb -D $PGDATA
USER root

RUN sed -i "s/^#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" $PG_CONF && \
sed -i "s/^#shared_preload_libraries = ''/shared_preload_libraries = 'plpgsql,pg_stat_statements'/" $PG_CONF && \
sed -i "s/^#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" $PG_CONF && \
sed -i '86s/.*/#&/' $PG_HBA && sed -i '88s/.*/#&/' $PG_HBA && \
echo "host    all             all             all                 md5" >> $PG_HBA

# Here I copy some files and stuff related to the database from my host machine to the container, they all combined have 4MB (in my local machine)

EXPOSE 5432

VOLUME  ["/etc/pgsql", "/var/log/pgsql", "/var/lib/pgsql"]

RUN yum -y remove acl gcc gcc-c++ vim unzip bison flex libtool gettext autoconf automake cpp kernel-headers \
gdb dyninst gcc-gfortran doxygen swig dyninst kernel-debug-devel && \
yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum && cat /var/lib/pgsql/echo.sh

USER postgres 

CMD ["/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data"]
```

I saw some other postgres images and most of them have less than 100MB. What can I do to decrease this size?

Comment: Many postgres images include their Dockerfile in a source GitHub repository, you can see how they achieve their size difference.

Comment: I couldn't actually see how they manage to do it. They use almost the same packages that I use, but the difference in size is enormous :(

Comment: You have to join the `yum remove` with the previous RUN statement (where the yum install is located), so, you will have only one layer that install the libs and tools (ex. GCC), build some dependencies and remove the used tools. With this approach, you will reduce the size of the final image and reduce the used layers.